# Passing a random number to Google search

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is to generate a random number between and creating a button that will google it.
I am stuck on creating the button to do so.

I am using the following code to generate a random number:

```
<div id="random" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);" >
```

How do I add functionality to a button which will Google that randomly generated number?

Right now, I am thinking on the lines of how we generate forms, which Google what the user types in them, for instance:

```
<form align = "center" action = "http://www.google.com/search"  target="_blank">
    <input name = "q"> <input type = "submit" value="Google !"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Just randomly generate 4 each time, its guaranteed to be fair. http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a form, a regular hyperlink would work just fine.

```
<a href="javascript: window.open('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001))">Google!</a>
```

Of course, you could use an image instead of text if you want to use a graphic button, and if you'd like to use a regular form button, the following would do the trick...

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001))" value="Google!" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially have the button build a query-string and do a location redirect.

I think the minimum string for a Google search results page would be something like:

[`https://www.google.com/search?q=RANDOM_STRING_HERE`](https://www.google.com/search?q=RANDOM_STRING_HERE)

Answer (score 1):

Solution with a form

**Markup:**

```
<form align = "center" action = "http://www.google.com/search"  target="_blank">
    <input id='random' type='hidden' name = "q"> 
    <input type = "submit" value="Google !"> 
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('random').value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. :) I tried it out and it went well. :)

```
<input type="hidden" name="random" id="random" value="" />
<input type = "submit" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('random').value =         Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001); window.location ='https://www.google.com/?#hl=en&output=search&q=' +document.getElementById('random').value"value="Google !"> </div>​
```